# its a query which needs to be addressed

Tags: mysql

There are two tables

```
Table 1
GroupName     Resolver
Aa                 A
Bb                 B
Cc                 C
Dd                 D

Table 2
key       UserId
1           B
2           C
```

And the output should A and D. That means records which are not present in table2 should come.

Comment: Use a subquery of the format WHERE EXISTS (...) or WHERE NOT EXISTS (...)

Comment: @Patashu this is the way to go instead of `NOT IN` since mysql can do a optimization http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/subquery-optimization-with-exists.html

Answer (score 1):

```
select GroupName,Resolver
from Table1
where Resolver not in (select UserId from Table2)
```

**[SQL Fiddle 1](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bff2b/1)**

**Another Query**

```
select t1.GroupName,t1.Resolver
from Table1 t1
left join Table2 t2 
on t1.Resolver=t2.UserId
where t2.UserId is null
```

**[SQL Fiddle 2](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bff2b/3)**

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from table1 t1 
left join table2 t2 on t1.Resolver = t2.UserId 
where t2.UserId is null
```

use a left join and check for null

**[SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bff2b/5)**

Comment: +1 since join should be faster

Answer (score 0):

Use the below query:

```
Select * from Table1 where Resolver NOT IN (SELECT UserId from Table2);
```

Comment: @user2416918 welcome mark this as accepted so that it will be useful to other users of SO.

Answer (score 0):

```
select t1.Resolver from Table1 t1, table t2 where t1.Resolver != t2.UserId
```